# Sudden Drop in CPU Utilization in macOS App After Extended Operation

Tags: macos, cpu

I'm struggling with CPU performance and memory optimization for a macOS app I'm developing.

The app I am developing consists of continuous real-time calculations and graphical elements. If I monitor the individual components, the CPU usage is as follows

- FetchAudioData (captures real-time data with Timer & performs calculations): 20%-30%.
- MEMU (graphics operation 1): 30% to 40%.
- FullScreen (graphics task 2): 20% to 40%.

I run the app and see a CPU load of 50% to 100% consistently, based on 600% full capacity.

However, after 3-4 hours of operation, the CPU utilization suddenly drops to around 10%. (It's hard to determine the exact cause because it's hard to monitor continuously during this time)

Additionally, I aware of some memory issues and are dealing with them, but they don't appear to be fatal leaks, so I relegated them to lower priority tasks for now.

At a crossroads, Should I prioritize code optimization, fix the small memory issue first, spend three to four hours of close monitoring, or perform a deeper understanding of the Mac system?

The analysis process through Profile in Instruments is also tricky in terms of catching the exact moment of a sudden change in CPU utilization.

I'd even be open to suggestions from iOS devs who might have any insights.

- I'm also wondering why the thread count in the picture goes into the 3000s after 3-4 hours.

I'm also wondering if this is an issue with asynchronous processing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated in the comments.

[image: Before / After 3-4 hours, 1-2 hours occationally]

Comment: “I'm looking for advice from people who have some experience … in iOS environments, not necessarily macOS.” but isn’t your issue with a macOS app?

Comment: Yes, but I think it would be good to ask for advice from people who have had experience with profile in instruments (in the iOS space), so if that's how I worded it and it's a problem, I'll change the wording.

Comment: It kinda sounded like you're asking for iOS engineers to help with a macOS problem. "not necessarily macOS" sounds (in the roundabout way north americans talk) like a polite decline than a literal not _necessarily_. Perhaps I'd phrase it like "I'd even be open to suggestions from iOS devs who might have any insights" or something like that

Comment: I understand the nuance you're pointing out. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737982?page=1#765567022
by: [ngb](https://developer.apple.com/forums/profile/ngb)

> you are probably having thread contention. they could be blocking each
> other. it is possible to overwhelm the system with too many threads.
> sometimes u get better utilisation with less threads. really u only
> want as many as you have cpu cores running at the same time otherwise
> they interrupt each other.
>
> u can look at the concurrency tool in instruments for some hints.

Comment: I've encountered another issue. Within Xcode, when checking via the CPU report, it indicates a decrease in usage. However, when observing through the activity monitor, there's no noticeable reduction. I'm curious as to why this might be the case.

Comment: it was Xcode bug, it seems same cpu rates on Activity Monitor after ~3 hours.